Geometry: necessary brick shape for 3D 90 degrees Herringbone pattern
I came across the Herringbone pattern and i was wondering, if one wanted it for a 3d construction, for the pattern and thus interlocking to exist in all 3 dimensions, what should the shape of the "brick" be? It seems hard to wrap my mind around that.

What exactly do you mean by the pattern’s existing in all three dimensions? What would be the 3-D version?

@PaulTanenbaum I mean for the L shaped 90 degrees zig-zag pattern to continue also in the depth (z axis), not only x,y

What gives you confidence that it can?

Hm, I don't know, thought should be possible. Is it not? I was thinking it might be possible with an L shaped brick (the two sides of the L being equal in length)

Converting the rectangles that herringbone-tile the $xy$ plane into L-shapes by giving them some thickness in the $z$ direction and then giving each a boxy chimney at one end of its roof would mean that you would be treating the $xz$ and $yz$ planes differently from the $xy$ plane, in which your tiles would look not like ells but like rectangles. Is such rotational asymmetry acceptable? And again, is it even possible?

I have no idea if it would be possible, as you can see I assumed it was, but maybe it's not. Yes, maybe the L shape is wrong, or maybe needs a Z or maybe a T shape (in this case the ratio of length-width would probably need to be 3:1). It's hard for me to visualize it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Here is a regular pattern in which 1×1×2 shapes in all three directions fill space.
Take a 2×2×2 cube and remove two opposite 1×1×1 cubes.  That can be built from three 1×1×2 dominoes, one in each direction.
Now to pack these to fill space.
The basic shape contains three cubes $$A=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$$ with sum $1$, and $$B=\{(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$$ with sum $2$.
The plane $x+y+z=1$ contains a triangle pattern of integer points, and it is easy to divide the points into groups of three that form small equilateral triangles that tile the plane.
Adjacent points in the plane $x+y+z=2$ can be chosen so our basic shape of six cubes tiles the pair of planes.
$$C_{m,n}=\{A\cup B\}+(2m-n,2n-m,-m-n)$$
Lastly, stack these to fill space.  Adding $(1,1,0)$ to each $C_{m,n}$ gives a basic shape in the planes $x+y+z=3$ and $x+y+z=4$, and so on.  $$D_{m,n,k}=C_{m,n}+(k,k,0)$$
